# Sprockets can't find TinyMCE from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spree, sprockets

I'm using Spree 0.70.3, Rails 3.1.3, and a custom fork of the Spree Editor plugin. (N.B. the relevant code for this fork hasn't changed from [master](https://github.com/spree/spree_editor).)

When I request a page which should get TinyMCE on a text area, I see this error in my development log:

```
Error compiling asset admin/all.js:
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'tinymce-jquery'
  (in <gemset-path>/bundler/gems/spree_editor-48cdfcfaf7bd/app/assets/javascripts/admin/spree_editor.js:9)
```

The line in question looks like this:

```
//= require tinymce-jquery
```

The editor depends on the `tinymce-rails` gem, which has a few candidates for the file in question:

- `assets/vendor/tinymce/jquery-tinymce.js`
- `assets/precompiled/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js`
- `assets/precompiled/tinymce/tiny_mce_jquery.js`
- `assets/integration/tinymce-jquery.js`

The [README for that gem](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) says the require line quoted above is correct, however. None of the gem's paths are in Sprockets' search path as shown by putting `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` into the console.

Should I be adding the gem's path to the Sprockets search path somehow, or is this something the gem isn't doing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you cannot  precompile the gem, I had a similar issue so what i did was to download the javascript plugin from the site manually  and copied the directories into my rails app. or i also tried to use a lower version of tinymce-rails gem and it worked.

Comment: Well, that sort of solved my problem; it got the gem working in development. Of course, I'm back to square one in production, with a different problem. (I downgraded tinymce-rails to 3.4.4, and required it in my app Gemfile instead of letting the spree_editor plugin require it.)

Comment: you can also try the git repo might help too

Comment: Looks like it did work in production; there was another issue which hid that it was fixed.